# Why does uptime want /dev/ttys021? "no such file or directory"

Tags: terminal, command-line, macos

When running uptime on Terminal.app on OS X Catalina, I'm seeing this error:

```
rcook@Richs-iMac (~ ): uptime
uptime: /dev/ttys021: No such file or directory
13:26  up 5 days, 21:09, 3 users, load averages: 1.93 2.43 2.45
```

How can I troubleshoot this?  Other programs such as "echo" or "ls" do not have this error.
I tried quitting Terminal.app and restarting.  No love.  Why is uptime looking for /dev/ttys021?
Note:  This question has been asked in another thread [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85520/uptime-dev-ttys003-no-such-file-or-directory) but the "answer" they came up with ("Just open up 21 more terminals.") was extremely unsatisfactory.
Thanks!

Comment: Does the problem persist after a reboot?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I guess it's "fixed" but I really want to know what caused it.  I guess I'll never know, unless it comes back again.  Sigh... thanks

Comment: I’m confused.  You say it doesn’t fix it, but it’s fixed.  Huh?

Comment: Nope, didn't say that.